# Regular expression Getting HTML Doctype

Tags: php, regex

My Html code is like this

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`

or this can be like this

`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN">`

I want to get the `Doc Type`  which will be like `"XHTML 1.0 Strict"` (for the first one), and `"HTML 4.0"` (for the second one) from it. What will be the regular expression code for this?
I like to use it in `PHP preg_match()` function.

Please help me in this case.

Comment: What's your use case?

Comment: For HTML5 it's only `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Any regex you come up with will _fail_ for that case.

Comment: I just can't leave this question without pointing OP to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the doctypes will be in the form shown, you could use

```
'#(?<=<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD )[^/]+#i'
```

So

```
preg_match('#(?<=<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD )[^/]+#i', html, $match);  
echo $match[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

How about using [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [`DOMDocumentType`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocumenttype.php)?

```php
$xml = new DOMDocument(); 
$xml->loadHTMLFile($url);

$name = $xml->doctype->publicId; // -//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN
```

`$doctype` now contains following values:

```
DOMDocumentType Object
(
    [name] => html
    [entities] => (object value omitted)
    [notations] => (object value omitted)
    [publicId] => -//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN
    [systemId] => http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd
    [internalSubset] => 
    [nodeName] => html
    [nodeValue] => 
    [nodeType] => 10
    [parentNode] => (object value omitted)
    [childNodes] => 
    [firstChild] => 
    [lastChild] => 
    [previousSibling] => 
    [nextSibling] => (object value omitted)
    [attributes] => 
    [ownerDocument] => (object value omitted)
    [namespaceURI] => 
    [prefix] => 
    [localName] => 
    [baseURI] => 
    [textContent] => 
)
```

So you can now easily extract type:

```
$name = $xml->doctype->publicId;
$name = preg_replace('~.*//DTD(.*?)//.*~', '$1', $name);
echo $name;
```

Which will result into `XHTML 1.0 Strict`. Working phpfiddle example [here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/1rs-eip).

Answer (score 1):

```
function contains($haystack, $needle){
    if (strpos($haystack,$needle) !== false) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
                $theDocType = "";
                $stringWithHTML = ""; // load some HTML in here from somewhere

                // Create DOM from HTML 
                $doc = new DOMDocument();
                //@$doc->loadHTMLFile("just_a_file.html");
                @$doc->loadHTML($stringWithHTML);

                // Grab document type
                $dtName = $doc->doctype->name;
                $dtPublic = $doc->doctype->publicId;
                if( $dtName="html" && $dtPublic!=""){           
                    // HTML or XHTML?
                    if(contains($dtPublic,"xhtml")){
                        $theDocType = "XHTML 1.0";
                    }else{
                        $theDocType = "HTML 4.01";
                    }
                    // Which type?
                    if(contains($dtPublic,"strict")){
                        $theDocType .= " (Strict)";
                    }elseif(contains($dtPublic,"transitional")){
                        $theDocType .= " (Transitional)";
                    }elseif(contains($dtPublic,"frameset")){
                        $theDocType .= " (Frameset)";
                    }else{
                        $theDocType = "XHTML 1.1"; // XHTML 1.1
                    }
                }else{
                    $theDocType = "HTML 5";
                }

                // Result
                echo $theDocType;
```

This will output things like:
XHTML 1.1
HTML 5
HTML 4.01 (Strict)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
   $html = file_get_contents("http://google.com");
   $html = str_replace("\n","",$html);
   $get_doctype = preg_match_all("/(<!DOCTYPE.+\">)<html/i",$html,$matches);
   $doctype = $matches[1][0];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'<!doctype.*?//dtd\s+([^/]*)//EN.*?dtd">'
```

That should work as pattern for your examples.

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression extracts everything between "DTD " and "/" without any syntax checking:

```
.*DTD\s+([^/]+)
```

This regular expression extracts the document type and checks some syntax in the string:

```
<!DOCTYPE\s+\w*\s*\w*\s*"[-//\w\d]*DTD\s+([\w\d\s.]*)[^"]*[^>]*>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this thread in the past, but in testing process, I detected a problem with some large doctypes. Some times, the developer split the doctype in 2 or 3 lines.
In this case, the usage of regular expression is no the best approach.

I paste an approach for doctypes in one or several lines:

```
<?
class Doctype {
    var $html;
    var $doctype;
    var $version;
    function Doctype($html){
       $this->html = $html;
       $this->extractDoctype();
       $this->processDoctype();
    }
    private function extractDoctype(){
        $preDoctype = "";
        $preDoctypeValid = false;
        $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $this->html);
        foreach ($lines as &$line) {
            $preDoctype = $preDoctype . $line;
            if(
                (strpos(strtolower($preDoctype), "<!doctype") !== false) && 
                (strpos(strtolower($preDoctype), ">") !== false)){
                $preDoctypeValid = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if($preDoctypeValid){
            //Store only the pattern: <! doctype >
            $pos1 = strpos(strtolower($preDoctype), "<!doctype");
            $pos2 = strpos($preDoctype, ">", $pos1) + 1;
            $preDoctype = substr($preDoctype, $pos1, $pos2);            
        }else{
            $preDoctype = "";
        }
        $this->doctype = $preDoctype;
    }
    private function processDoctype(){
        $version = "";

        $pattern_html5 = "/<!doctype\s+?html\s?>/i";
        if (preg_match($pattern_html5, strtolower($this->doctype))) {
            $version = "HTML5";
        }else if(strpos(strtolower($this->doctype), "xhtml") !== false){
            $version = "XHTML";     
        }else if(strpos(strtolower($this->doctype), "html") !== false){
            if(strpos(strtolower($this->doctype), "3.2") !== false){
                $version = "HTML 3.2";  
            }
            if(strpos(strtolower($this->doctype), "4.01") !== false){
                $version = "HTML 4.01"; 
            }
            if(strpos(strtolower($this->doctype), "2.0") !== false){
                $version = "HTML 2.0";  
            }
        }else{
            $version = "OTHER";
        }
        $this->version = $version;
    }
    public function getDoctype(){
        return $this->doctype;
    }
    public function getDoctypeVersion(){
        return $this->version;
    }
}
?>
```

https://github.com/jabrena/WTAnalyzer/blob/master/r_php/document/Doctype.class.php